# Unable to register a user in django deployement on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, web-deployment, heroku-postgres

I've deployed a django-blog web-app on heroku. Its working but with an error. When i register a new user it says user created but when I try to login through registered user it says username and password didn't match.
And when I login in my admin panel then the user i registered wasn't created at all.

Here's my `settings.py` file

```
import os
import django_heroku

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'myblog/media')

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydjangoblogapp.herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blogapp.apps.BlogappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myblog.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'max_similarity': 1,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
os.makedirs(STATIC_TMP, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(STATIC_ROOT, exist_ok=True)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blogapp:post_list'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')


AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_LOCATION = 'media'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

The problem seems to be with the database on heroku. I'm using PostgreSQL When I run heroku addons it shows me that I've hobby-dev database-

```
Add-on                                      Plan       Price  State
──────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────  ─────  ───────
heroku-postgresql (postgresql-rigid-77895)  hobby-dev  free   created
 └─ as DATABASE

The table above shows add-ons and the attachments to the current app (myblogapplication) or other apps.
```

I just downloaded postgresql on my machine and didn't set it up accordingly maybe and that's why its creating this error. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create user as superuser, if you are registered user through your form you can't able to login through admin panel. Django has a security features to prevent login from admin panel if not superuser.

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Verify your local database, if it inserted properly but it is not mandatory in django because django will raise error in console but as a developer you can verify it. You can also verify is_superuser = 0 in database.

Comment: You pick my qustion wrongly. I want to create a user for my app not for django admin panel. I've user and profile model in my `models.py` I said the new user I registerd for app wasn't created in the database at all.

Comment: You have installed postgress but still you are not changed in settings.py. You have to change your DATABASE section engine to postgresql_psycopg2. Please refer this section to configure postgres https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: If the data is not inserted you will get an error. Please post your error too